# How do I run an method async inside a class that is being used with asyncio.create_server?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, autobahn

I'm using autobahn with asyncio and I'm trying to make a method inside a class that extends WebSocketServerFactory run every x seconds.

This is how the documentation on the autobahn website does it:

```
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketServerFactory
factory = WebSocketServerFactory()
factory.protocol = MyServerProtocol

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = loop.create_server(factory, '127.0.0.1', 9000)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
```

I have simply replaced the WebSocketServerFactory class with a class that extends it, and I want to run a method inside it every x seconds.

I found an example of this on the autobahn website, but it uses twisted and not asyncio.

Here is an short example([original and full version](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/blob/master/examples/twisted/websocket/broadcast/server.py)) of what I want, but the example uses twisted:

```
class CustomServerFactory(WebSocketServerFactory):

def __init__(self, url):
    WebSocketServerFactory.__init__(self, url)
    self.tick()

def tick(self):
    print("tick!")
    self.do_something()
    reactor.callLater(1, self.tick)
```

How can I achive the same thing using asyncio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your example, the same functionality with asyncio can be done using the asyncio event loop: [Asyncio delayed calls](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#delayed-calls).

So in your example that would mean something like this:

```
def tick(self):
    print("tick!")
    self.do_something()
    loop.call_later(1, self.tick)
```

where loop is the asyncio event loop variable you create earlier in:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

Comment: Passing the loop to the class and then using self.loop.call_later seems to be working great. Thanks!